# Array of array of structs

Tags: c++, arduino, avr

Is it possible to declare an array consisting of other arrays (with variable sizes) consisting of structs in C++? It would be really nice if there was an easy and efficient way (using for) to iteration over all structs inside an element of the array.

The struct is defined like this:

```
struct Number
{
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

For example, the data is something like:

```
{
    { {0,0}, {0,1} },
    { {0,0}, {0,1}, {1,0}, {0,0} },
    { {0,0}, },
    { {0,0}, {4,0} }
}
```

I would like to use this for a self made clock consisting of an Arduino Uno, an Ethernet shield, an RTC and a LED array. The solution shouldn't use more memory than needed. That's why I don't use a two dimensional array.

Comment: If you can't use `std::vector<std::vector<Number>>`, you're probably left on providing your own implementation for it.

Comment: So you want C or C++? Your question is contradictory. On one side, your asking for C/C++ solution, and your question has c++ tag, on the other side your stating you are using gcc compiler.

Comment: The answer to your question is no, the things you are asking for are in the `C++ Standard Library`.  Maybe you can find another library that implements something similar to a `std::vector`.

Comment: I rewrote the confusion lines, I really would like to learn C++ so that's why I'm using C++.

I was trying a solution like this:
`Number N0[] = { {0,0}, {1,1}, {2,2}, {4,4} };
Number N1[] = { {6,0}, {1,3}, {1,2} };
Number N2[] = { {7,0}, {1,2}, {0,2}, {4,8}, {6,6} };
Number *Numbers[] = { N0, N1, N2 };`

But then I don't know how to iterate through the elements of Numbers[0];
So Numbers[0][0]->x gives me 0,0 and Numbers[0][1]-x gives me 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `Number* var[];` or `Number** var;`. Case closed :)

EDIT: oh, you swapped to C++... Than save yourself a headache and use the std::vector. Well... you can make your own Vector even in C, but no templates.

Comment: I ended up using your solution, thank you also to the others that responded.

The vector implementation for Arduino from GitHub got me much weird data corruptions errors which I couldn't fix. This is also a bit faster and I think uses less memory (and especially program memory).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Standard C++ For Arduino](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus/blob/master/README.md). It [implements](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus/blob/master/vector) a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

With that, you can use a vector of vectors

```
struct Number
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

using MultiNum = std::vector<std::vector<Number>>;
```

However, it is of a worthy note that, Arduino's memory is really small, and you should really have upper bounds to your memory usage. A `vector` of a `vector` without smartly using `reserve` may waste some memory...

Another option is:

```
Number x[][4] =
    {
    { {0,0}, {0,1} },
    { {0,0}, {0,1}, {1,0}, {0,0} },
    { {0,0}, },
    { {0,0}, {4,0} }
    };
```

Of cause, that dictates the *fixed* memory *consumed* at compile time. (A 4x4 Matrix of `Number`).

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is memory, you can always declare `Number **var` and manually allocate and reallocate space when you need to.